# Modifying Attributes in h5py

Tags: python, h5py

I'm working on a program where I need to change attributes on multiple files quickly, but I'm running into a problem where calling `attrs.modify` causes a hangup followed by a crash randomly. It doesn't happen every time, but it happens often.

What I want to do is grab the attribute (which is an array), change one value, then store it in the file. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
    import h5py
    import time
    
    fname = '/path/to/file'
    
    for i in range(20):

        f = h5py.File(fname,'r+')

        att_val = f['grp/dset'].attrs['att']
        att_val[0][2][1] = time.time()
        f['grp/dset'].attrs.modify('att',att_val)
        f.close()
        print(f'{i} complete.')
```

Comment: Since this is an array, you may need to modify the way you access the data. Use `att_val = f['grp/dset'].attrs['att'][;]`. (Note `[:]` added at the end.) This will return the attribute as a NumPy array instead of a h5py object. The following lines should work without modification.

Comment: Just notice a typo above. That should be `att_val = f['grp/dset'].attrs['att'][:]`. (Note `[:]` added at the end.)